# Discrepancies in ElasticSearch Results

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a relatively simple search index built up for simple, plain text queries. No routing, custom analyzers or anything like that. One search instance/node, one index.

There are docs within the index that I have deleted, and the RESTfull API confirms that:

GET /INDEX_NAME/person/464

```
{
  "_index": "INDEX_NAME",
  "_type": "person",
  "_id": "464",
  "exists": false
}
```

However the doc is being returned from a simple search

POST /INDEX_NAME/person

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "person.offices",
            "query": "Chicago"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

One of the rows that is returned:

```
{
  "_index": "INDEX_NAME",
  "_type": "person",
  "_id": 464,
  "_score": null,
  "fields": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm new to ElasticSearch and thought I finally had a grasp of the basic concepts before digging deeper. But I'm not sure why a document isn't accessible via REST but it is still appearing in the results?

I'm also running into the reverse issue where docs are returned from the API but they are not being returned in the search. For the sake of clarity I am considering that a separate issue for the time being, but I have a feeling that these two issues might be related.

Part of me wants to delete my index and rebuild it, but I don't want to get into the same situation in a few days (and I'm not sure if that would even help).

Any ideas or pointers on why this discrepancy might be happening? Maybe a process is in some zombie state and elasticsearch just needs to be restarted?

Comment: I must say it looks like a bug. If you are able to recreate it, sending it to elasticsearch forum is the only hope :)

Comment: This has had everyone I asked stumped, so it might just be a bug!

Comment: Interesting! Could you please provide your current index settings? Just go to 'localhost:9200/_settings' from your browser. Anything strange there?